# Internet explorer breaks footer and yes I've tried the sticky footer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, footer, sticky

AS the title says, I'm having trouble with a website footer, For whatever reason I can't seem to figure out why the footer breaks, i've tried a multitude of sticky footer options I've found via google but non seem to really work or throw off my code completely. Any help would be greatly appreciated, still learning as I go!

```
@import url("reset.css");

@font-face {
font-family: 'Maiandra';
src: url('fonts/MAIAN.TTF');
}

/* Static Header */

#header {
background-color: #676767;
height: 35px;
font-family: Maiandra;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center

}

/* Body */

html {      
position: relative;
min-height: 100%; 
}

body {
font-family: Maiandra;
font-size: 15px;
color: #333;
margin: 0 0 60px;
}

p {
padding: 10px;
}

p strong {
font-weight: bold;
}

#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 800px;
overflow: visible;
height: 100%
}



/* Content Area */

.content {
float: right;
background: #FFFFFF;
width: 600px;
overflow: sroll;
padding-bottom: 100px;
}


.leftcolumn { 
background: #ffffff;
width: 175px;
float: left;
}

.rightcolumn {
width: 175px;
float: right;

}

img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-top: 2px;
}

h1 {
font-family: Maiandra
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;

}

h2 {
font-family: Maiandra;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

h3 {
font-family: Maiandra;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

h4 {
font-family: Maiandra;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

h6 {
font-family: Maiandra;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
}



 /* Static Footer */

.footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
width: 100%; 
background: #E8E8E8;
text-align: center;
font-family: Maiandra;
color: #000000;
font-size: 12px;
border-style: solid;
border-top: 1px solid #7F7D7D;
overflow: auto;
}

.footer p{
margin-top: 5px;
height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer!

added this to my HTML..

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">-->
<!--<!DOCTYPE HTML>-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```